# Subquery for returning the most recent foreign key less than equal to a date

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-design, django-queryset

I have two models, Rank and Product. Rank has a foreign key Product. Every day a new Rank is created for each product. However, occasionally an error happens and some date may not have a Rank object for a Product. Therefore, I am trying to return a QuerySet that grabs the most recent Rank object less than or equal to `date_str` for every Product object.

`date_str` can be any arbitrary date. If several Products do not have Rank objects with a `pub_date` equal to `date_str` this queryset should return the most recent Rank in the database before `date_str`.

I thought this function would work, but it fails to return anything at all when an exact match for `date_str` is not found for every single Product's Rank.

```
date_str = '2020-04-27'


def get_queryset(self):
    r = super().get_queryset().filter(pub_date__lte=self.date_str)
    return r.filter(
        pub_date=Subquery(
            (Rank.objects
                 .filter(product=OuterRef('product'))
                 .values('product')
                 .annotate(last_updated=Max('pub_date'))
                 .values('last_updated')[:1]
            )
        )
    ).order_by('-day_rank')
```

Comment: Does it work when `date_str` exists? So you're saying it just doesn't work when `date_str` is None?

Comment: @RossMechanic sorry for the confusion, I attempted to clarify the question. The date_str will always exist with a desired date in the past. However, the queryset does not return anything unless every single product has a rank object for that date. If a single Product does not have a Rank for date_str, nothing returns.